# Extract text between last slash and last dot using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string like this in javascript

`at LoggerService.log (/Users/apps/api/webpack:/pcs-goc-api/pcs-libs/logger/src/logger.service.ts:107:29)`

I want to extract `logger.service` from it. the formula is between last `/` to last `.`

I can extract from last `/` using `/([^\/]+$)/g` but don't know how to limit the finding to last `.`

Note: these are other examples:

`at LoggerService.log (/Users/apps/api/webpack:/pcs-goc-api/pcs-libs/logger/src/logger.ts:107:29)` 
expected: `logger`

`at LoggerService.log (/Users/apps/api/webpack:/pcs-goc-api/pcs-libs/logger/src/logger.js:107:29)` 
expected: `logger`

`at LoggerService.log (/Users/apps/api/webpack:/pcs-goc-api/pcs-libs/logger/src/api.logger.service.ts:107:29)` 
expected: `api.logger.service`

Comment: Rudimentary but solves the case you've asked for `^.*\/(\w+\.\w+).*$`

Comment: @Cjmarkham I ran via regexer it select the whole line

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/HlZbFu/1 you want the first group.

Comment: Ok, since your edit I can say that regex won't work now you've shown more examples.

Comment: Thanks @Cjmarkham I updated with more examples, the regex is only handle two words

Comment: Try `s.match(/\/([^\/\s]*)\.[^\/\s]*$/)[1]`. Or, more conforming to your rules: `s.match(/.*\/(.*)\.[^\/.]*$/)[1]`. Well, even `/.*\/(.*)\./` should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
/.*\/(.*)\./
```

*Details*:

- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `\/` - a `/` char
- `(.*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `\.` - a `.` char.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const text = "at LoggerService.log (/Users/apps/api/webpack:/pcs-goc-api/pcs-libs/logger/src/api.logger.service.ts:107:29)";
const match = text.match(/.*\/(.*)\./)
if (match) {
    console.log(match[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We can try using a regex replacement approach here:

```js
var log = "at LoggerService.log (/Users/apps/api/webpack:/pcs-goc-api/pcs-libs/logger/src/api.logger.service.ts:107:29)";
var output = log.replace(/^.*\/|\.[^.]*$/g, "");
console.log(output);
```

The regex pattern here says to match:

- `^.*\/` all content from the start up to and including the LAST /
- `|` OR
- `\.[^.]*$` all content from the LAST dot until the end

Then, we replace with empty string, leaving behind the string we want.

Answer (score 1):

```
([^\/]+)[.][^:]+:\d+:\d+
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/FeLRmi/1

- `[.]` => "." character
- `[^:]` => Any character except ":"
- `[^:]+` => One or more `[^:]`
- `:\d+` => One or more digits after ":"

All the other regex statements are your own.